# Why does mkdir not work with wildcards?

Tags: bash, mkdir

```
nathan@gentoodesktop ~/Documents $ mkdir test
nathan@gentoodesktop ~/Documents $ mkdir te*/test
mkdir: cannot create directory 'te*/test': No such file or directory
nathan@gentoodesktop ~/Documents $ cd te*
nathan@gentoodesktop ~/Documents/test $ mkdir test
nathan@gentoodesktop ~/Documents/test $ ls 
test
```

Comment: This is a little confusing, as the question is about a different error, just the third answer adds this as additional finding ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern only ever expands to *existing* names, and the pattern `te*/test` does not match any existing name. Note that `te*/test` is one complete pattern and that the `te*` part is not matched separately from `/test`.

Since the pattern does not match (and since the `nullglob` and `failglob` shell options are not set) it is left unexpanded and given to `mkdir`, which complains when it can't create the subdirectory `test` in the directory `te*`.

The command `cd te*` succeeds because the pattern `te*` matches the name of the existing directory `test`.  If there had been more names that matched `te*`, you may have received an error from `cd`.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this kind of problems with appropriate switches. The first one is `-v`, which will produce more output, which you can consult. The other one one is `-p`, which will create parent directories if they're not present. Playing with these both should give you a good lesson. Eg.:

```
mkdir -pv _dirname_
```